# How efficiently post a tweet with a remote image with Nodejs Stream?

Tags: node.js, http, twitter, pipe, node.js-stream

I need to download a remote image, that its path is saved on the `wineTweet.label` attribut.
And then POST a tweet with this image.

My implementation is working, but I first save the image to a file and then read it before posting it.

Here is the code :

```
    var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
    https.get(wineTweet.label, function (response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function () {
            var data = require('fs').readFileSync('file.jpg');
            // Make post request on media endpoint. Pass file data as media parameter
            client.post('media/upload', {media: data}, function (error, media, response) {
                if (!error) {
                    // If successful, a media object will be returned.                            // Lets tweet it
                    var status = {
                        status   : 'I am a tweet',
                        media_ids: media.media_id_string // Pass the media id string
                    }
                    client.post('statuses/update', status, function (error, tweet, response) {
                        if (!error) {
                            console.log(tweet);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

How to directly connect ReadingStream to the POST request ?

Comment: Which library are you using for posting tweets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `response` directly, which is already a Readable stream, instead of writing/reading a temporary file:

```
https.get(wineTweet.label, function(res) {
  // Make post request on media endpoint. Pass file data as media parameter
  client.post('media/upload', {media: res}, function(error, media, response) {
    if (!error) {
      // If successful, a media object will be returned.                            // Lets tweet it
      var status = {
        status   : 'I am a tweet',
        media_ids: media.media_id_string // Pass the media id string
      };
      client.post('statuses/update', status, function(error, tweet, response) {
        if (!error)
          console.log(tweet);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

On an unrelated note, you *should* handle errors appropriately instead of ignoring them.

Comment: that is working. This is just a snipet for demo, so now I will handle errors.